# Adobe Flash Peer-to-Peer Application

Tags: flash, air, chat, p2p

I am doing a meeting system that display documents (PDFs) for end-users using Adobe Flash AS3 and Adobe Air. as a requirement we need to develop some interactive tools between end-users alike chat, sending files, polls and such stuff, but I should do it based on peer-to-peer connection. (No client/server method is allowed due to cost and security reasons)

My question is: **Can flash through Flash/ActionScript/Air do such application that communicates peer-to-peer? And what is the code or method to do it?**

Answer (score 4):

yes, it can - you'll want to check out adobe stratus which is currently in beta:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/

danny patterson has some good information on it:
http://www.dannypatterson.com/labs.cfm

but... you do have to connect to the rtmfp server at some point, but i believe that all the information is passed peer-to-peer after that... so I'm not sure if it'll work in your case, but it's worth checking out:)

Comment: That's a 4 year old link to a beta technology, so I'm not surprised. I'm no longer doing actionscript development, but it's been renamed Cirrus: http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Cirrus, sample app here: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/